# What Eclipse plugin do I need in order to build an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am taking on the maintenance for an Eclipse plugin, but it is failing to resolve import dependencies for packages such as `org.eclipse.core.resources`.

I suspect I may need to install an Eclipse plugin or Eclipse plugin development, but the recursive definition is hampering my search efforts.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

I am using Eclipse Helios ("For Java Developers"), and would like avoid upgrading/reinstalling if I can (despite the datedness of the IDE).

Comment: Usually you can find that by going through Eclipse's Software Update Sites and look for the site offering plugin development components. I can't remember the exact name, unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was `Eclipse Plugin-in Development Environment`.